# How to add an extra temp date column using the select query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select, netezza

I am trying to add an extra date column in the select statement using a certain where condition.

Below is my current table:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVfnG.png)

I want to add an extra Date column which is add all date between >=Start and <= End-2.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKzSg.png)

Getting error with this query:

```
SELECT 
    *, temp_Date AS Date  
FROM 
    Mytable  
WHERE
    Date >= Start AND Date <= End - 2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use text instead of images.

Comment: whenever you get an error, you should include the error in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this statement as dummy data:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    id int not null,
    startDate date not null,
    endDate date not null,
    val int not null
)

insert into MyTable
values
(10,'20171106','20171112',7),
(10,'20171106','20171112',6),
(10,'20171106','20171112',5),
(10,'20171106','20171112',0),
(10,'20171106','20171112',2)
```

Using [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) you select each tuple as your starting date and increment that date until it reaches the enddate like this:

```
;WITH rc AS (
   SELECT id, startDate, endDate, val
      , startDate AS temp_date
   FROM MyTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, startDate, endDate, val
      , DATEADD(DAY,1,temp_date)
   FROM rc
   WHERE DATEADD(DAY,1,temp_date) <= enddate
)
SELECT *
FROM rc
```

You should be aware the recursion in SQL-Server is expensive and slow on larger data. Also remember to hint the maximum recursive loop amounts as the default is 100. Example:

```
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

The 0 would be unlimited recursions, with the risk of running infinitely.

As I read you are using a data warehouse and as such it should have a time or date dimension. In such case a simple join would do the work:

```
SELECT id, startDate, endDate, val
, date_sid AS temp_date
FROM MyTable AS m
INNER JOIN DimDate AS dd
ON dd.date_sid >= startDate
AND dd.date_sid <= endDate
```

Please consider not using reserved keys for column names (like start, end or value)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select M.*
       , Temp_date = Datediff(day, M.start, dateadd(day,-2,M.end))
from   MyTable M
```

Comment: Thanks StelioK for the quick reply. I am  querying in Netezza so I doubt datediff is available.
The above query gives an error stating Temp_date not found.

Comment: Oh, I apologize for that. I didn't realize you weren't using sql server. I guess try and find the equivalent fucntion in Netezza.